# setting nested collectionview number of cells equal to array

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, nsarray, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionview nested inside a collectionview cell and I need the number of cells in that collectionview to be equal to a dictionary value that the super cell carries.

So to reiterate, each cell is a room object and contains a title, a description and an array of members. I want the members.count to equal the number of cells inside the interior collection view for that specified index.

It originally thought that it would be best to set this in the the super cells cellForItemAtIndexPath function as seen below,

```
if section == 0 {

    cell = liveCell

//  these work fine

    let room = rooms[indexPath.row]
    liveCell.liveStreamNameLabel.text = room.groupChatName
    liveCell.descriptionLabel.text = room.groupChatDescription

//  this does not
    liveCell.profileCV.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) = room.members?.count

    return cell

}
```

but it appears that `numberOfItems(inSection: )` is a get method.

I tried accessing the array count at the actual interior collectionviews numberOfItemsInSection function however it returns zero each time.

```
lazy var homeController: HomeController = {
    let hc = HomeController()
    hc.liveCell = self
    return hc
}()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

//    does not work
//    let room = homeController.rooms[indexPath.row]
//    return homeController.room.count

//  doesn't crash but returns zero everytime
    return homeController.rooms.count
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: you mean you need to set number for items for each collectionview?

Comment: @MohammadBashirSidani yes, but the number of items for each cell varies on the number of members that are in each cell.

Comment: and do you know the number of cells of each nested collectionview?

Comment: @MohammadBashirSidani that value should be provided by `room.members?.count`

Comment: Each collection view should have a unique tag (main one tag is 0, first nested tag is 1, second 2 etc). You should have an array of numbers like let array = [1,2,3] where each number represent the number of cells in the collection view array[0] return the number of cells in collection view of tag 0 and so. And in number if items in section return array[collectionView.tag]. Does this help?

Comment: @MohammadBashirSidani I'm not too sure I understand. I'm using collection view cells that have a collectionview inside of them. I'm trying to set the number of cells on the interior collection view using data from the cell